# Connect to remote host from Aptana Studio 3 terminal

Tags: ssh, symfony1, terminal, aptana, aptana3

How to connect to remote host from **Aptana Studio 3 terminal view**, and use commands on that server?

I'm using symfony framework, the project is in my host 192.168.0.100, so I want to run symfony commands like: `$ symfony propel:build-schema`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To connect to a remote host run the following command in your console:

```
$ ssh -l <username> 192.168.0.100
```

Enter your password and you're golden. Unfortunately you have to do this every time you open Aptana, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: If you want to use a private key: `$ ssh -l <username> -i </path/to/key> 192.168.0.100`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative if you need to specify a port number(or dont need to).

```
ssh <username>@<server> -p <portnumber>
```

i know its a old question but hope it helps someone.

first post as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Target Management (http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) to create a remote project in aptana.